# Height of textarea is not setting correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to set the width(178px) and height(178px) of my table to the width and height of the text area on click of a button.Width(178px) setting works fine, but height is set only for 17px(I guess some kind of slicing of 8 from 178px is happening--need help in this part).I tried element.style.height, element.offsetHeight, element.clientHeight, element.getBoundingClientRect().height
Everything results the same.I referred many posts in SO regarding this...many developers are getting problem in setting the height but width wrks fine fr them.What could be the reason?Thanks.

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="chan()">change</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function chan() {
        var w=document.getElementById('num').getBoundingClientRect().width;
        var h=document.getElementById('num').getBoundingClientRect().height;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=w+" "+h;
        document.getElementById('cache').style.width=w+"px";
        document.getElementById('cache').style.height=h+"px";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: check your console, you'll see something like: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null`

Comment: see this https://jsfiddle.net/qu7L920k/ its working fine

Comment: @Nivetha Does your table has width and height 178px?if so https://jsfiddle.net/qu7L920k/2/

Comment: @Amal https://jsfiddle.net/1t0qobaa/ pls check this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `table` style `display: inline;` to `display: table;` to get its height perfectly.

```
table {
  display: table;
  width: 178px;
  height: 178px;
}
```

> display: inline : Displays an element as an inline element
>
> display:table : Let the element behave like a `table` element

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  /*not working for list2_tab_ta*/
}

input {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: grey;
}

#clr {
  margin-left: 190px;
  margin-bottom: 13px;
  padding: 5px;
}

table {
  display: table;
  width: 178px;
  height: 178px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: powderblue;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
}

textarea {
  display: inline;
  /*readonly: true;*/
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="number" id="operator1">
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="text" id="operand1">
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="number" id="operator2">
  </li>
  <li>=</li>
  <li>
    <input type="number" id="result">
  </li>
</ul>
<button id="clr">Clear</button>

<ul>
  <li>
    <table id="num">
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>+</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>-</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>*</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>/</td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </li>
  <li>
    <textarea id="cache"></textarea>
  </li>
</ul>

<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="chan()">change</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function chan() {
        var w=document.getElementById('num').getBoundingClientRect().width;
        var h=document.getElementById('num').getBoundingClientRect().height;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=w+" "+h;
        document.getElementById('cache').style.width=w+"px";
        document.getElementById('cache').style.height=h+"px";
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: table style display:inline-block gives me what I want: )

Comment: table should be `display: table`.you can set `display:inline-block` for li.see this http://jsfiddle.net/1t0qobaa/1/ Also find the difference between both https://jsfiddle.net/rq0xrwp5/